# iOS photo library: can unique identifier reuse after asset delete?

Tags: ios, phasset, phphotolibrary

I have an app the check changes in the Photo library. My app uses the PHAsset local identifier to follow any changes that happened with this asset.

My question is if the user delete an image from the photo library, can the photo app use this identifier for future images?

Comment: As a matter of policy, I would assume that it's not impossible.

Comment: Probably, no it can't.